# OpenApi Swagger - Failed to load remote configuration

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc

I have my swagger ui on adress
http://exampleadress.com/swagger-ui/index.html

Address tried to get swagger-config from http://exampleadress.com/services/v3/api-docs/swagger-config, but url where swagger-config is right now is http://exampleadress.com/v3/api-docs/swagger-config.

How to make redirect to swagger-config file?
I using org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.7.0

Spring boot 2.7.13 application.

I read about springdoc.swagger-ui.path property, but where I should set this property? In application.yaml?